# How to disable shortcuts in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I'm working in a scientific calculator project using Qt5, I'm using the QTextEdit as the calculator's display.
I want to disable the shortcuts like (Ctrl + A, and Ctrl + C) in the display, so How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using QTextEdit as a display only, why not using QLabel instead?

Comment: Well, I choose QTextEdit because it has scroll bars by default, and I need scrolls. Also I plain to edit the text in future versions.

Comment: Then QListWidget might be a option too. By the way, why do you want to prevent users from copying text from the calculator display? I would think that users would like to do that.

Comment: Look, this is my first project, so there is lots of things that I don't know about, Like QListWidger, which I will read about.
I don't want to prevent the user from copy,but from select all, because if the user select contents and press any button in the calculator all of the text in the display will be exchanged with the clicked button text. I hope you understand What I mean. Anyway when the project finish I will give you a link for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Key Filter Method, Create an Event Filter that returns false for the Hot Keys. It's a little tedious, but should work out.

Comment: Would you give me a link or point me where to read about "Key Filters"

Comment: i found this, let me know if it helps. Not very detailed, but should help you get started. http://www.qtforum.org/article/14293/qtextedit-how-to-turn-off-keys-intercepting-like-ctrl-z.html

Answer (score 1):

Event filtering on the LineEdit is the proper way to do it, then you can ignore the ones you do not want or override the behavior.

A dirty shortcut (no pun intended) to try is to create a QShortcut and and assign it to an empty slot. Qt will probably complain about ambiguous shortcuts and will probably do not do anything with it.
Dirty I know :)

```
QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+A"), parent);
QObject::connect(shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), receiver, SLOT(emptySlot()));
```

May be you can even ignore the connect part...